# Why is this \def not working as expected?

Tags: listings

I am having a weird problem with \def. I am new to (La)TeX and can't figure this out.

I have a simple code as follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
language=C++,
tabsize=4
}

\def\docend{\end{document}}

\def\codeend{\end{lstlisting}}

\begin{lstlisting}

class AClass
{
    enum Types
    {
        t_one = 1
    };
    ~AClass()
    {
        cout << _T("destructor") << endl;
    }
} 

 \end{lstlisting}

%  \codeend

\docend
```

Using `\codeend` gives an error '...emergency stop...no legal \end found...". However, `\docend` works fine.

What mistake have I made? (FYI, using TeXMaker with Miktex 2.9 on Windows 7.)

Comment: What’s the purpose of `\docend`? It’s better readable for others to leave the original definition.

Comment: Agreed. I used \docend to check if \end had a specific behavior , and kept it here for illustration. I don't use it in actual .tex file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package `listings` changes the catcodes to get a verbatim listings. That means, that `\end{lstlisting}` is not executed the normal way, because the backslash is a normal character and `\end` is a string, not a macro. Thus `listings` explicitly looks for `\end{lstlisting}` in the input file and does not find it, if it is hidden in `\codeend`.

At least, the `listings` package offers to make your own environments using `\lstnewenvironment`, see section "4.16 Environments" of the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

**Addition:**

An environment `cpp` (as suggested in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156235/why-is-this-def-not-working-as-expected/156238?noredirect=1#comment357348_156238)) can be defined as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{cpp}{%
  \lstset{%
    language=C++,
    tabsize=4,
  }%
}{}

\newcommand*{\docend}{\end{document}}

\begin{document}

\begin{cpp}
class AClass
{
    enum Types
    {
        t_one = 1
    };
    ~AClass()
    {
        cout << _T("destructor") << endl;
    }
}
\end{cpp}

\docend
```

Comment: Wow! But can it be done the \codeend way, if so how? I ask this because I have \codestartX (X for C++ etc) and want to keep things consistent tag name wise.

Comment: OK, I'd rather use \begin{cpp} and \end{cpp}, which is also quite fine by me. (I posted the earlier comment about the same time as you edited the answer.) Thanks.